# VMware Workstation linux installation stuck at "clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc"

Tags: linux, installation, vmware, vmware-workstation

During installation XCP-ng 8.2.1, installation stuck at "clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc".

I had the same problem with Virtual Box but this command "vboxmanage setextradata "%machine_name%" VBoxInternal/CPUM/HostCPUID/80000006/edx 0x02009140" helped me and now it's working. But right now i need Vmware.

Other distributions/linux working fine, no problem with proxmox e.t.c.

I tried to change the boot options by adding `clocksource=hpet` and `clocksource=acpi_pm` but no changes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Work through this VMware KB and see it helps.  ......   https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2057907#:~:text=On%20some%20Linux%20distributions%2C%20VMware,command%20in%20a%20terminal%20window.